Merging Structure Trees of Two Tagged PDFs Using PDFBox Overlay
I'm currently working on a project where I need to merge two PDF files, both containing accessible tags (structure trees). I'm using the Overlay class in PDFBox to overlay the content of these PDFs. However, I'm encountering an issue where the structure trees from both input PDFs are not being merged. The output PDF only contains the tags from the input PDF.
Here's the code I'm using:
    try (PDDocument overlayDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new  RandomAccessReadBufferedFile(overlayPdf));
         PDDocument inputDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new RandomAccessReadBufferedFile(inputPdf))) {
        
        Overlay overlayer = new Overlay();
        
        overlayer.setInputPDF(inputDocument);
        overlayer.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDocument);
        
        Map<Integer, String> ovmap = Map.of();            
        PDDocument result = overlayer.overlay(ovmap);
        
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(inputPdf.getName()) + "_overlay.pdf";
        result.save(new File(inputPdf.getParentFile(), fileName));

}

It isn't supported. I wrote the structure tree merge and split codes (despite having only minimal understanding about it ) and I have no idea what would have to be done, i.e. where and how to insert the tree.
